# Longest path in a tree

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given an undirected weighted tree with $n$ vertices, how can I design an algorithm that is $O(n^2)$ and other that is $O(n)$ for finding the longest path between two nodes in the tree (without repeating vertices or edges)?

Intuitively I think that running BFS or DFS twice might work for an $O(n^2)$
algorithm, and Dijkstra's algorithm for an $O(n)$ algorithm. I'm new into this kind of analysis so I'm not sure how to show that this works (proof or pseudocode), or if this is actually correct.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/279265/finding-the-longest-path-in-an-undirected-weighted-tree

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4242100/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/143683/755. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).